# Plugin with shortcode, missing .js and .css files when used in widget areas

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget, shortcode

I'm working on a WordPress plugin which works perfectly if I insert the shortcode in a page or an article, but if I insert the shortcode in a widget area the .js and .css files aren't loaded.

```
//CUSTOM JS FUNCTIONS
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_functions' );
function my_functions() {
    wp_register_script( 'my-script-1', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
} 

//CUSTOM CSS
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_css' );
function my_css() {
    wp_register_style('my-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css' );
}

//INCLUDE JS IF SHORTCODE EXIST
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'form_my_include' );
function form_my_include() {

    global $post;

    if (strstr($post->post_content, 'my_form_shortcode')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('my-script-1');
        wp_enqueue_style('my-css');
    }
}

//SHORTCODE
function my_shortcode_add(){
    ob_start();
    include("include/my_function.php");
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_add');

// Enable shortcodes in text widgets
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enqueue your script and stylesheet directly inside the shortcode. You can also load both the script and stylesheet inside the same `wp_enqueue_scripts()` hook.

```
//CUSTOM JS FUNCTIONS
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_and_stylesheets' );
function my_scripts_and_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_script( 'my-script-1', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_style('my-css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css' );
} 

//SHORTCODE
function my_shortcode_add(){
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script-1'); //loaded here
    wp_enqueue_style('my-css'); //loaded here
    ob_start();
    include("include/my_function.php");
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_add');

// Enable shortcodes in text widgets
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Your current code grabs to content inside post, and checks for the shortcode in there. Depending on where your shortcode is called, it might not actually be present in the post content, despite being present on the page.

By adding the `wp_enqueue_script()` & `wp_enqueue_style()` to your shortcode function, it will enqueue your whenever your shortcode is present on a page, regardless of where on the page it is.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your plugin.

```
// Enable shortcodes in text widgets
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');
```

This code simply adds a new filter allowing shortcodes to run inside widget.

Comment: Added filter, but doesn't work, js and css doesn't load.